# What is the best means of securely delivering minion specific files using Salt?

Tags: salt-stack

I have a number of files that I need to transfer to specific minion hosts in a secure manner, and I would like to automate that process using Salt. However, I am having trouble figuring out the best means of implementing a host restricted transfer.

The salt fileserver works great for non-host-specific transfers. However, some of the files that I need to transfer are customer specific and so I need to ensure that they are only accessible from specific hosts. Assumedly Pillar would be the ideal candidate for minion specific restrictions, but I am having trouble figuring out a means of specifying file transfers using pillar as the source.

As far as I can tell Pillar only supports SLS based dictionary data, not file transfers. I’ve tried various combinations of file.managed state specifications with paths constructed using various convolutions (including salt://_pillar/xxx), but thus far I have not been able to access anything other than token data defined within an SLS file.

Any suggestions for how to do this? I am assuming that secure file transfers should be a common enough need that there should be a standard means of doing it, as opposed to writing a custom function.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on what exactly you're trying to secure. If only a part of the files involved are "sensitive" (for example, passwords in configuration files), you probably want to use a template that pulls the sensitive parts in from pillar:

```
# /srv/salt/app/files/app.conf.jinja
[global]
user = {{ salt['pillar.get']("app:user") }}
password = {{ salt['pillar.get']("app:password") }}
# ...and so on
```

For this case you don't need to care if the template itself is accessible to minions.

If the entire file(s) involved are sensitive, then I *think* you want to set up the file_tree [external pillar](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/pillar/all/salt.pillar.file_tree.html), and use file.managed with the contents_pillar option. That's not something I've worked with, so I don't have a good example.

Comment: Thank you. The "external pillar" link looks like it might do the job for me. It's whole file(s) that I need to transfer (reports, binaries, etc), as opposed to templated config files.

Comment: The pillar.file_tree module that you pointed me to looked like it would do the job, but the module doesn't show up on my systems. Is that an enterprise only module? Or can I download the pillar.file_tree module from somewhere? I am currently using the community edition.

Comment: Got it working, using pillar.file_tree. Works excellent! Thanks for your help.

Comment: According to the docs, it was added in v2015.5.0 and last changed in 2018.3.0; if you have an old version it might be missing. I don't think it's enterprise specific.

Comment: Never mind, I see you got it sorted out. Glad to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution Synopsis: Using PILLAR.FILE_TREE**

A: On your master, set-up a directory from which you will server the private files (e.g: /srv/salt/private).

B: Beneath that create a “hosts” subdirectory, and then beneath that create a directory for each of the hosts that will have private files.

- /srv/salt/private/hosts/hostA
- /srv/salt/private/hosts/hostB
- … where hostA and hostB are the ids of the target minions.
- See the docs if you want to use node-groups instead of host ids.

C: Beneath the host dirs, include any files you want to transfer via pillar.

```
echo “I am Foo\!” > /srv/salt/private/hosts/hostA/testme
```

D: In your master config file (e.g: /etc/salt/master), include the following stanza:

```
ext_pillar:
 - file_tree:
      root_dir: /srv/salt/private
      follow_dir_links: False
      keep_newline: True
      debug: True
```

E: Create a salt state file to handle the transfer.

```
cat > /srv/salt/files/base/foo.sls << END
/tmp/pt_test:
  file.managed:
    - contents_pillar: testme
END
```

F: Run pillar refresh, and then run your state command:

```
salt hostA state.apply foo
```

Following the last step, hostA should have a file named /tmp/pt_test that contains the text “I am Foo!”.